# Convert SQL to PL/SQL For "IF NOT EXISTS"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have some SQL code that I want to convert into PL/SQL for Oracle, however I'm struggling to find a good alternative for the "IF NOT EXISTS" function. Can someone help?

Here's the SQL that needs converting:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SEC_ConfigSetting WHERE ItemKey='Version')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SEC_ConfigSetting
               ([VersionNo]
               ,[Section]
               ,[ItemKey]
               ,[ItemValue]
               ,[ItemType])
         VALUES
               (1,4,'Version','V1.4.0',0)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        /* Update database version */
        UPDATE [SEC_ConfigSetting]
        SET [ItemValue] = 'V1.4.0'     
        WHERE ItemKey='Version'
    END
```

Comment: In Oracle, use `MERGE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok, can you show me how this is done?

Comment: fyi, that isn't [SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info). `merge` is, however, so the tag can stay.

Comment: then what is it? @WilliamRobertson

Comment: Looks like T-SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing looks like you need [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

```
merge into SEC_ConfigSetting s
  using (select 1 VersionNo, 4 Section,'Version' ItemKey,'V1.4.0' ItemValue, 0 ItemType from dual) d
  on (s.ItemKey = d.ItemKey)
when matched then update set
  ItemValue = d.ItemValue
when not matched then    
  INSERT (VersionNo, Section,ItemKey,ItemValue,ItemType)
  VALUES (d.VersionNo, d.Section, d.ItemKey, d.ItemValue, d.ItemType);
```

And this can be used as a plain SQL or as part of PL/SQL script.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error report:

SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: Square brackets have no place in Oracle identifier names (unless you've created them using double-quotes, e.g. "[VersionNo]", in which case, you'd have to surround all references to them in doublequotes.

Comment: @Boneist Right. I haven't thought about that when retyped from question.